# What is this line checking

Tags: c++, c++14

In this piece of code how does the line:

> if ((i & (1 << j)) > 0)

find all possible subsets in an array of numbers with length `n`?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>

    using namespace std;

    void allPossibleSubset(int arr[],int n)
    {
        int  count = pow(2,n);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                            if ((i & (1 << j)) > 0)
                                    cout << arr[j] << " ";
                    }
                    cout << endl;
            }
    }

    int main(){
            int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
            int n = 10;
            allPossibleSubset(arr, n);
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Put more details of the issue that you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

The code

> ((i & (1 << j)) > 0)

is performing a bitwise AND of i with left shift of 1 by value of j. For example: 
if i = 1, j = 0 then result of the above expression will be :

```
(1 & (1 << 0)) 
(1 & 1)
= 1
```

the result is expression will be > 0 (zero)

case two: when i = 2 and j = 1 the result will be (2 & 2) which is equal to 1 and hence the result of expression will be > 0 (zero)

Answer (score 0):

To get to the bottom of this, you need to know that there are `2^n` possible subsets of a set `S` of size `n`. In other words, the powerset of a set of `n` elements is of size `2^n` (that is the `count` in your example).

Now given this piece of information, you can construct an enumeration of the set S. Each subset will have its own unique number. As a programmer, you will start numbering from `0` and, since there are `2^n` elements, stop at `2^n - 1` (this is the first loop). If you write this number `i` in binary, you can take the bit at position `j` as an indication of whether the array element at index `j` is present in the subset `i`.

The condition you have asked about, is true when bit `j` in number `i` is one, in other words when array element at index `j` is included in subset `i`.

Not that the piece of code will probably not work as expected if you try it for anything bigger than 64 (assuming you compile for a 64bit machine with GCC, because then the integer has 8 bytes).